# How to check whether the data exists in database irrespective of column name?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table with four columns with each consisting an email in them. I want to check whether the data exists in any of the four columns without performing particular column queries, I mean

```
SELECT * FROM 'table_name' WHERE 'column_1'='data';
SELECT * FROM 'table_name' WHERE 'column_2'='data';
SELECT * FROM 'table_name' WHERE 'column_3'='data';
SELECT * FROM 'table_name' WHERE 'column_4'='data';
```

Is there a way to achieve it. I have restricted to 4 columns and what if the column count was very large? Thank You.

Comment: Means, the table name is fixed but column name is dynamic. It will check all the columns of that table. Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there are only 4 columns, you can do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE 'data' IN (column_1, column_2, column_3, column_4);
```

Comment: What if I there were 100 columns or unknown column count?

Comment: You had mentioned in your question that there were only 4 columns so that's why the solution was for 4 columns. If you have a set number of columns, you can add them in the `IN` clause. If you don't have a set number of columns, then you need to look at dynamically generating your query which can be messy and a lot of work.

Comment: And which is described in the 2nd duplicate topic...